# Unity objects and terrain exporter

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, export, terrain, .obj

I am trying to export a terrain and models in a unity evironment to an .obj file. I have a code which exports a terrain properly and also one which exports the models properly. When I try to combine them, the models (inside unity!) jump to the corner of my terrain. To get the data of the terrain I use Terrain.activeTerrain, and for the models I use Selection.gameobjects. I do not alter the environment through my script.
Does anyone know whats going wrong here?

Comment: you'll probably get a better answer if you show how you are trying to "do both".

Comment: ... and by posting it on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com as it sounds like it's not related to a programming task/issue.